# Creating an QGIS Action to change a field value from yes to no

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, actions

So I'm working on a project where I have to check the classification of a bunch of points in a QGIS project. I have created a styling which means I can perform this task with visual inspection.
I have a field simply called 'check' with default value of 'no', which I then change to 'yes' when I have checked a point.

Is there any way to create an action so that I can simply click on a point and auto-change its value to yes without having to open my attribute table every time?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple Python action to do just that. Open the layer properties dialog for your point layer and click on the 'Actions' tab. Click on the green cross to add a new action and configure the action as shown in my screenshot below (you can use whatever name and description you like for your action- this is just an example):

[image]

Paste the code snippet below into the editor, making sure the field name string matches yours (I take it your field is called 'check') and click 'OK'.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer_obj = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
fid = [%$id%]
fld = layer_obj.fields().lookupField('check')
with edit(layer_obj):
    layer_obj.changeAttributeValue(fid, fld, 'Yes')
```

Now, when your point layer is active, you will notice that the 'Actions' tool icon is enabled.

[image]

You can click on it to activate the action you just created. You will see that the map tool cursor is now a cross, and when you click on a feature, its attribute value in the 'check' field will be updated to 'Yes'. By the way, if you have overlapping points, you will get a small dialog with a list of the 'stacked' feature ids, and you can select the one you want to update (or update them all). Once you are finished, simply select a different map tool to deactivate the action.