QGIS: format attribute table to match template and auto populate certain columns
I'm looking to perform 2 tasks

make an attribute table match to a template attribute table, so only the columns that are in the template table exist, currently using refractor, but wonder if there's a better way.

auto populate several columns in the attribute table which have the same text each time.



some simple python with an action can do what your asking - just a little time setting it up. see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358989/276

Note that the "Refactor fields" tool allow you to perform your two task at the same time by using the "source expression" column to fill field

Thanks for the comments. My python knowledge is non existent to trying to keep this as simple as possible. I can get this to work editing the source expression but have to edit this every time I run the process. Is there a way to save the changes permanently?

@ J.R how is this done using source expression please.

You can write a short script as @Mapperz suggests.   To get the fields in the template attribute table you can use:
sel_layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
print(sel_layer.name())
self.dlg.label_layer.setText(sel_layer.name())
layer_data = sel_layer.dataProvider() #not required      
fields = layer_data.fields()
for field in fields:
    field_list1.append(str(field.name()))
    print(field.name())

